# How to Use Recursion to Generate Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, recursion

I am trying to generate all possible arrays with values from 1 - 9 using recursion in python. My code is below:

```
totalArr = []

def recursion(arr, n):
    for i in range(9):
        if (arr[i] == 0):
            arr[i] = n
            if (n < 8):
                recursion(arr, n + 1)
            else:
                print(arr)
                totalArr.append(arr)

recursion([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 0)

print(len(totalArr))
```

When I run this code, all I get is the single array below:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I am aware that I can use permutations to the arrays, however for my use case of these arrays, I believe that recursion is better in the long run.

Comment: `arr[i] == n` does not assign `n` to `arr[i]`. You need `=`, not equality operator.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Welcome to SO! "I am aware that I can use permutations to the arrays, however for my use case of these arrays, I believe that recursion is better in the long run." Permutation != recursion. The definition of "all possible arrays with values 1-9" *is* all permutations of an input array with those values, and you can do this recursively, which is what you appear to be attempting. What is the problem with your code (infinite loop due to `==` typo aside)?

Comment: "however for my use case of these arrays, I believe that recursion is better in the long run"... why do you believe that?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that typo. The problem with my code is that all the arrays it creates are the same [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: Are you looking for `itertools.permutations(range(10))`?

Comment: Hey Mateen. I have a version of my code where I use itertools permutation function, but I have a set of conditions I want my arrays to meet at the end, and using that method, I have to filter them out after they're generated. If I end up being able to use a function like the one I have above, I'll be able to filter them as they're being created

Comment: What are the set of conditions? (To make sure we meet them.)

Answer (score 0):

```
totalArr=[]
def permute(lst,n):
    ''' O(n!), optimal'''
    if n==1:totalArr.append(lst.copy())
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            lst[i],lst[n-1] = lst[n-1],lst[i]
            permute(lst,n-1)
            lst[i],lst[n-1] = lst[n-1],lst[i]
lst = [i for i in range(1,9)] # any other lst with unique elements is ok
permute(lst,len(lst))
print(totalArr)
```

This method can generate all permutations using divide-and-conquer algorithm

Comment: When I run your code, all it generates is arrays filled with zeros [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: @LukeSchultz, there's a line missing in this code where it actually calls `permute()`.  My guess is something like `permute([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 9)` before the `print()` statement.

Comment: Yes. You should firstly apply function `permute` in a lst with its length, and then get  the result in `totalArr`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python program to print all permutations with
# duplicates allowed

# Function to print permutations of my_array
# This function takes three parameters:
# 1. my_array
# 2. Starting index of the my_array
# 3. Ending index of the my_array.
def permute(a, l, r):
    if l==r:
        print a
    else:
        for i in xrange(l,r+1):
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
            permute(a, l+1, r)
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] # backtrack

# Driver program to test the above function
my_array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = len(my_array)
a = list(my_array)
permute(a, 0, n-1)
```

We are doing permutation by using recursion with backtracking :
More info on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/